# Не работает параллакс в jquery

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, parallax

Делаю параллакс эффект на сайте. Но он, почему-то, не верно считает количество пикселей, на которое должны сместиться блоки.
Также не работает скролл колеса в обратную сторону.
Все работало хорошо до добавления части кода в jquery, где я задаю блокам высоту (чтобы на любом разрешении экрана, блоки были на всю высоту экрана).
Странно. Как это может влиять? Там вроде бы все логично.
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

```js
var div1Height = $('.div2_1').height();
var div2Height = $('.div2_2').height();
var div3Height = $('.div2_3').height();


$('.div2_1').css('height', div1Height - 50);
$('.div2_2').css('height', div2Height - div3Height - 50);

var div1Height = $('.div2_1').height();
var div2Height = $('.div2_2').height();

var div2Top = div1Height + 50;
$('.div2_2').css('top', div2Top);

var div3Top = div2Top + div2Height;
$('.div2_3').css('top', div3Top);

// Создание эффекта параллакс
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
    parallaxScroll();
});

function parallaxScroll(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div1Position = $('.div2_1').position().top; 
 var div2Position = $('.div2_2').position().top;
 var div3Position = $('.div2_3').position().top;

    $('.div2_1').css('top',(div1Position -(scrolled*.35)));
    $('.div2_2').css('top',(div2Position -(scrolled*.35)));
    $('.div2_3').css('top',(div3Position -(scrolled*.35)));
}
```

```css
.div1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3PMJz0z2Ndk/hqdefault.jpg);
}

.div2 {
 position: relative;
}

.div2_1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: url(https://oboi.ws/wallpapers/18_11890_oboi_derevjannyj_zabor_1152x864.jpg);
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 z-index: 2;
 margin: 50px 0;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.div2_2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
 background: url(https://wallpapers-fenix.eu/lar/151007/013640779.jpg);
}

.div2_3 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 325px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 4;
 background: url(https://besthqwallpapers.com/Uploads/23-12-2018/75543/thumb-blue-texture-with-cracks-blue-ground-blue-creative-texture-cracks-art.jpg);
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Site</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="div1">
 </div>
 <div class="div2">
  <div class="div2_1">
  </div>
  <div class="div2_2">
  </div>
  <div class="div2_3">
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, проблему вдалось решить таким образом: 
Первое - создаем функцию, начинающую работать при полной загрузке документа. В нее помещаем и рассчитывание высоты блоков, их отступов; и обьявление переменных.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div1Height = $('.div2_1').height();
    var div2Height = $('.div2_2').height();
    var div3Height = $('.div2_3').height();

    $('.div2_1').css('height', div1Height);
    $('.div2_2').css('height', div2Height - div3Height);

    var div1Height = $('.div2_1').height();
    var div2Height = $('.div2_2').height();

    var div2Top = div1Height;
    $('.div2_2').css('top', div2Top);

    var div3Top = div2Top + div2Height;
    $('.div2_3').css('top', div3Top);

    // Создание эффекта параллакс
    $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
        parallaxScroll();
    });

    div1Position = $('.div2_1').position().top; 
    div2Position = $('.div2_2').position().top;
    div3Position = $('.div2_3').position().top;
});

function parallaxScroll(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('.div2_1').css('top',(div1Position -(scrolled*.35)));
    $('.div2_2').css('top',(div2Position -(scrolled*.35)));
    $('.div2_3').css('top',(div3Position -(scrolled*.35))); 
}
```

```css
.div1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3PMJz0z2Ndk/hqdefault.jpg);
}

.div2 {
 position: relative;
}

.div2_1 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: url(https://oboi.ws/wallpapers/18_11890_oboi_derevjannyj_zabor_1152x864.jpg);
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 z-index: 2;
 margin: 0;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.div2_2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
 background: url(https://wallpapers-fenix.eu/lar/151007/013640779.jpg);
}

.div2_3 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 325px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 4;
 background: url(https://besthqwallpapers.com/Uploads/23-12-2018/75543/thumb-blue-texture-with-cracks-blue-ground-blue-creative-texture-cracks-art.jpg);
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Site</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="div1">
 </div>
 <div class="div2">
  <div class="div2_1">
  </div>
  <div class="div2_2">
  </div>
  <div class="div2_3">
  </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Не знаю почему, но выдавало ошибку, если переменные div1Position, div2Position, div3Position объявлялись через var
Здесь же все заработало.

Вывод: 
Все скрипты создавать после полной загрузки документа (возможно с некоторыми исключениями).
Следить за местом объявления переменных. В т.ч. не объявлять переменные внутри функций.